# Calculate angle from the floor

Tags: ios, swift, trigonometry, core-motion, euler-angles

I need to find an specific angle from iPhone CoreMotion data (pitch, yaw, roll, or quaternions). Lets imagine two lines. The first one should go perpendicularly from phone to the floor. Second one should point to the place where camera is looking at (if camera was working, then start of this line would be at the camera, and the end at the place displayed in the center of camera preview). And I need to find an angle between these two lines. I have no idea where to start, can someone help?
[image]

I have all the data from CoreMotion, so pitch, yaw, roll / gravity x,y,z, Attitude.quaternion/rotationMatrix.

Comment: Start with [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D%5Bcore-motion%5D+angle).

Comment: A small diagram will help both you and the people helping you place the data you have (from accelerometer, maybe even compass) and derive the math for the one you want. Nothing fancy, just sketch something up in paper and take a picture.

Comment: I added the diagram, and the data. Thanks.

Comment: Time to whip out an old trigonometry text book ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have all parameters then hope in this way you will be able to find the required angle

θ = (1/Sin)(opposite/hypotenuse)

[image]

Comment: A diagram alone isn't a helpful answer. It can't be searched or referenced. You should update your answer with some relevant description of the solution, including formulas.

Comment: Yes i have added the formula as all the params are available so i have suggested with the diagram

Comment: As I said, a picture can't be searched or referenced. [Edit] your answer and include, as text, the relevant details.

Answer (score -1):

Needed to change way of looking at this. First I realized, that yaw was not affecting this at all. The solution was Pythagoras pattern with pitch and roll as parameters, so:

```
sqrt(pow(pitch, 2) + pow(roll, 2))
```

---

Actually this is still not working best when phone is slightly rotated over yaw axis. Don't know why, I'll try to figure it out. But it's small error, and it's only visible, when pitch is close to 90 degrees.